# Indentify Changed Cells on Button Click

Tags: vba, excel

On clicking a button in my Excel sheet, I would like to know the cell that has changed.

I have written a macro to `POST` the changed value to an API that will return a value. I don't want to do this calculation in VBA as it doesn't satisfy the requirements of the rest of my application.

My current function so far,

```
Sub MyChangeSub()
    'Get value/s and name of cell/s that has/have changed
    Dim query, request As String, result As String
    request = "{ ""cell"":""" & cell_name & """, ""value"":""" & value & """ }"

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlHttp.Open "POST", URL, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlHttp.send (request)

    result = xmlHttp.responseText
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    ' Doing something with the result and update the values
End Sub
```

How do I get the value of any cell that has changed? Right now I want to apply the change for just one changed cell. Later I can modify it to get the values of multiple changed cells.

Comment: You handle the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: @GSerg. I'm sorry, I should have added that this is literally my first time working on VBA and Excel and have only pieced together the above code using SO and other resources. I'm not sure what the `change` event does.

Comment: If you handle them one at a time with the `Worksheet_Change` event, it will pass a parameter called `Target` that will let you know which cells have changed. If you want to do them all at once, you would need to keep track of all of these targets.

Comment: There are two different ways you could do this - one is the way @Chrismas007 just posted - you add each target to a range and then you have a list of all of the cells that have changed. This is probably the way I would go. This won't work however if you change one cell and then change it back - it will still say that it was changed (which is true, but the value may not have)

Comment: [On this link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) you can read about Worksheet_Change. This is a pre-created Sub that each Worksheet has (apart from other useful ones) and it will be triggered everytime a cell is changed.

Comment: The other way to do it is create a copy of your worksheet initially and then compare the values between sheets - probably not as elegant or easy, but will actually get you the values that have changed better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a global range. Every time you change something, add that range to your global range.  On click, highlight all cells that are in the global range.

```
Public ChangeRng as Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    If ChangeRng Is Nothing Then
        Set ChangeRng = Target
    Else
        Set ChangeRng = Application.Union(ChangeRng, Target)
    End If       
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cel as Range
    For Each cel in ChangeRng
        cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
    Next cel
    Set ChangeRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably what I would do, but keep in mind that the cell values may have not changed - for example, if I change `40` to `4` and then back to `40`, it will say that it has changed. It has, but the value has not.

Comment: Chrismas, I think you also need to initialize the ChangeRng. `If ChangeRng Is Nothing Then Set ChangeRng = Target Else Set ChangeRng = Application.Union(ChangeRng, Target)` Otherwise, you get a debug error right off the bat. Also, OP - this goes in a worksheet object since I know you don't know much about excel VBA - make sure you paste the code into the sheet you would like it to work on.

Comment: Thanks @user1274820 I agree.  Was thinking about that when I wrote the original post and forgot to go back and update.